# Django 2.0 вывод пользователей из админки

Tags: python, django

Задача следующая, выгрузить посредством классов-представлений всех данных о пользователях в .html шаблон. т.е. вот этих:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С возможностью CRUD для этих записей
P.S.Находил видео с реализацией этого, но там выполнялось через создание новых моделей, и с выгрузкой в них значений из админки. Выглядит, на мой взгляд, слишком громоздко и не удобно.
Буду рад любой помощи с реализацией.

P.P.S. Все делалось по данному руководству: [ресурс](https://djangoforbeginners.com/custom-user-model/), соответственно реализовано через расширение стандартной модели (если это важно).

Answer (score 2):

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserListView(ListView):
    model = User
```

**user_list.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        ...
    </tr>
  {% for user in user_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: и как эти значения вывести в template файле?

Comment: Да вы, должно быть, шутите... Добавил к ответу.